# Malloc not creating memory

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc, allocation

I have quite a seemingly simple problem that feels like it's going to have a very straight-forward answer. I've used *malloc* in this way several times before but for some reason it's not allocating enough memory to contain the data from the file - despite being new to C, I feel as though I'm overlooking something painfully obvious and it's frustrating me. Any help would be appreciated.

FILE

> --------- USERS ---------
>
> ID : 0
>
> Name : Chris
>
> Gender : m
>
> Age : 21

CODE

```
const int BUFFER = 64;
char **fileContent;
int i;

// Code that opens file - tested

fileContent = (char**)malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(char*));

for(i = 0; i < BUFFER; i++)
{
    fileContent[i] = (char*)malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(char));
    fgets(fileContent[i], BUFFER, fp);
}
```

I know some of the practices are poor above but this is such a segment I isolated for testing purposes. The problem I'm having is that only the first line of the file is being read into the **fileContent** array. The VS debugger looks something like this...

> fileContent                    0xblah {0xblah "--------- USERS ---------\n"}
>
> ```
>                            0xblah "--------- USERS ---------\n"
>
>                            45 '-'
> ```

The two names that should come below fileContent (I'm assuming **fileContent[i]**) aren't there. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you sure this is a code problem rather than not knowing how to use the debugger? What happens if you enter `fileContent, 64` in the watch window? - also, *Malloc not creating memory* should be easy to figure out by checking if the returned pointer is not 0.

Comment: @Alluziion: A compilable / executable example would be nice. I also don't quite get why you use `malloc()` for `fileContent` instead of declaring it `char * fileContent[ BUFFER ]`. My stare-down debugging comes up empty right now...

Comment: Are you sure your input file doesn't have any trailing spaces behind the visible content? Lines longer than 64 bytes will lead to unexpected behaviour since fread() won't read the whole line.

Comment: malloc doesn't creates memory...it ALLOCATES memory :-D

Answer (score 1):

Your code seem right. check the return value of malloc. 
eg

```
fileContent[i] = (char*)malloc( BUFFER * sizeof(char) );
if ( fileContent[i] == NULL )
{
    printf( "Error in memory allocation." );
    exit( -1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The debugger just doesn't know when to stop reading each entry in the array. It has no idea that it should read 64 bytes from `fileContent[0]` and then 64 more from `fileContent[1]` -- how could it?